# gnuplot: Label undefined values with "NaN" in a 2D scatterplot

Tags: label, undefined, gnuplot, nan, scatter-plot

I have a data file which looks roughly like this

```
# X  Y   Value
1    1   1.5
1    2   2.5
2    1   NaN
2    2   3.0
```

I want to create a scatter plot in Gnuplot with crosses at each point and a label with the value beside it.

```
set datafile missing "NaN"
plot "data.txt" using 1:2:3 with labels left, \
     "data.txt" using 1:2 with points
```

I would like to see a label with a literal string `NaN` for the points with an undefined value. Instead no label is printed. **Is there a setting to force undefined values to be printed?**

I tried this, but still no labels for undefined values:

```
plot "data.txt" using 1:2:(($3==$3) ? $3 : "NaN") with labels left
```

It looks like the undefined points are skipped altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works just fine for me (gnuplot 4.4 and gnuplot 4.6):

```
plot 'data.txt' u 1:2:3 w labels left,\
     'data.txt' u 1:2 w points
```

In fact, copy/pasting your original code works for me as well:

```
set datafile missing "NaN"
plot "data.txt" using 1:2:3 with labels left, \
     "data.txt" using 1:2 with points
```

Perhaps you're not noticing the labels because they are almost off the screen?

```
set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:3]
```

helps them to be a little easier to see...

Comment: Ok, shame on me. I dumbed down my example too much without testing it. There is a difference between `using 1:2:3` (NaN is printed) and `using 1:2:($3)` and more complicated expressions where functions are called -- the functions are not even evaluated. Now I found out that `valid(n)` can be used for this: `using 1:2:(valid(3) ? sprintf('%.0f', $3) : "NaN")`. Thanks anyway, your answer helped me a lot!